# .NET Runtime 2.0 Error in a service

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, 64-bit

We have a custom service that writes to a DB (SQL 2005).  This is a full 64-bit environment (DB, .NET service).  On one of our servers we crash every morning when we have a spike in our volume of data.  On another server we run fine.  The only differences that I've been able to notice between the two machines is that the one experiencing the crash has .NET 3.5 also installed.

Has anyone else seen this type of behavior?

Here is the event log entry from the crash today:

Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1000
Date:       11/6/2008
Time:       09:35:03
User:       N/A
Computer:   RDDARWIN02
Description:
Faulting application servicehost.exe, version 2.0.6.6, stamp 48eb7b7a, faulting module  kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4062, stamp 462643a7, debug? 0, fault address  0x0000000000027d8d.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink  /events.asp.
Data:
0000: 41 00 70 00 70 00 6c 00   A.p.p.l.
0008: 69 00 63 00 61 00 74 00   i.c.a.t.
0010: 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 20 00   i.o.n. .
0018: 46 00 61 00 69 00 6c 00   F.a.i.l.
0020: 75 00 72 00 65 00 20 00   u.r.e. .
0028: 20 00 73 00 65 00 72 00    .s.e.r.
0030: 76 00 69 00 63 00 65 00   v.i.c.e.
0038: 68 00 6f 00 73 00 74 00   h.o.s.t.
0040: 2e 00 65 00 78 00 65 00   ..e.x.e.
0048: 20 00 32 00 2e 00 30 00    .2...0.
0050: 2e 00 36 00 2e 00 36 00   ..6...6.
0058: 20 00 34 00 38 00 65 00    .4.8.e.
0060: 62 00 37 00 62 00 37 00   b.7.b.7.
0068: 61 00 20 00 69 00 6e 00   a. .i.n.
0070: 20 00 6b 00 65 00 72 00    .k.e.r.
0078: 6e 00 65 00 6c 00 33 00   n.e.l.3.
0080: 32 00 2e 00 64 00 6c 00   2...d.l.
0088: 6c 00 20 00 35 00 2e 00   l. .5...
0090: 32 00 2e 00 33 00 37 00   2...3.7.
0098: 39 00 30 00 2e 00 34 00   9.0...4.
00a0: 30 00 36 00 32 00 20 00   0.6.2. .
00a8: 34 00 36 00 32 00 36 00   4.6.2.6.
00b0: 34 00 33 00 61 00 37 00   4.3.a.7.
00b8: 20 00 66 00 44 00 65 00    .f.D.e.
00c0: 62 00 75 00 67 00 20 00   b.u.g. .
00c8: 30 00 20 00 61 00 74 00   0. .a.t.
00d0: 20 00 6f 00 66 00 66 00    .o.f.f.
00d8: 73 00 65 00 74 00 20 00   s.e.t. .
00e0: 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00   0.0.0.0.
00e8: 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00   0.0.0.0.
00f0: 30 00 30 00 30 00 32 00   0.0.0.2.
00f8: 37 00 64 00 38 00 64 00   7.d.8.d.
0100: 0d 00 0a 00               ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to attache a debugger to the running code before the crash?  Maybe you can track down where the problem is.

You could also use adplus to get a dump of the process and then use that dump in windbg to help track down the problem.  Something like this should give you the dump file you are looking for:

adplus -crash -pn servicehost.exe

Comment: TonyB that is an awesome suggestion, if for no other reason than I didn't know about ADPlus.  I even had the MS Debugging tools already installed but didn't know about this one command line tool.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In reviewing my old questions, I realized this problem went away with an .NET update at some point.  Anyway, since your suggestion was something new I learned, I'm just going to say you got the correct (and only) answer.